# RSTL with Web 8.5

Tags: web8, content-delivery, odata

I'm looking for an updated version of the RSTL tag library. I'm in need reference the latest version of RSTL source and was wondering if it supports Tridion 8.5 yet ? Hope Mihai finds my question :)

Comment: Mihai also has code on Github. That's more likely to be current than Google Code https://github.com/mitza13/yet-another-tridion-blog

Comment: Looks like the code has not been touched since 2013 so very doubtful that it has been updated for 8.5. His blog pages for the library have also been removed.

Comment: I have not touched RSTL since 2013. I don't even remember if it's updated to Tridion 2013 or just Tridion 2011. I know the code has been used in some partner implementations, but I was not involved.

Comment: This turned to be a defect in the 8.5 SDL library.  The most recent patch fixed issues with parameters the RSTL library was dependent on.